# Carousel javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css-transitions, carousel

How can I make the 2nd image(the bottom) stay in place till the 1st image(the active) completely finish `transition` in place? and then start the loop again without reordering the array? I don't know if this is completely wrong or if I'm missing something, I've been trying for a while! please explain your comment/answer, thanks for helping.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var slideShowSlide = document.querySelector('.slideshow__slide');
  var slideBgFigure = Array.from(slideShowSlide.children);
  var slideWidth = slideBgFigure[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;

  for (i = 0; i < slideBgFigure.length; i++) {
    slideBgFigure[i].style.transform = "translateX(-" + slideWidth + "px)";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slideBgFigure.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  slideBgFigure[slideIndex - 1].style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
  setTimeout(carousel, 3000);
};
```

```css
.slideshow__slide {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 359px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide__bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #f0f0f0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #f0f0f0;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.slide__bg img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="slideshow__slide slide">
  <figure class="slide__bg current">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/620x200/070" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="slide__bg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/620x200/700" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="slide__bg">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/620x200/007" />
  </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: Why the down vote??? could you just try to explain?

Comment: I also wonder :)) such an interesting question.

Comment: seriously is bad that im still learning and I have a question? Thanks @Hu

Comment: I don't know, I myself like this question. I can kinda understand what you want, it's not too long with a full runnable code provided. I also wonder why people downvote it, and yet without an explanation :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this question got 2 downvotes? Maybe it wasted people's time? It wasted my whole morning too, damn...

Here might be what the OP wants to get. I used CSS animation to control animation instead of javascript, setInterval instead of setTimeout. I use javascript to control which slide whose the class `current`. But it turned out the most tricky time-consuming part of me is not animation, but `z-index`. I got a typo and it messed up too. Holy damn, took a lot of time to do this looks easy problem.

---

**Edit:** The simpler code, use CSS transition instead of animation, the javascript code just permutate the classes.

```js
var slideShowSlide = document.querySelector('.slideshow__slide');
var slideBgFigure = Array.from(slideShowSlide.children);

function permutateClassname(array) {
  var tmp = array[0].className;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    array[i].className = array[i + 1].className;
  }
  array[array.length - 1].className = tmp;
}

function carousel() {
  permutateClassname(slideBgFigure);
}

setInterval(carousel, 3000);
```

```css
.slideshow__slide {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 359px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide__bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #f0f0f0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #f0f0f0;
}

.slide__bg img {
  display: block;
  opacity: .3;
}

.slide__bg {
  transition: transform 1.5s ease-in;
}

.slide__bg.slide-out {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  z-index: 0;
}
.slide__bg.slide-in {
  transform: translateX(0);
  z-index: 2;
}
.slide__bg.middle {
  transform: translateX(0);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="slideshow__slide slide">
  <figure class="slide__bg slide-out">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/620x200/070" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="slide__bg slide-in">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/620x200/700" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="slide__bg middle">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/620x200/007" />
  </figure>
</section>
```

Useful link: https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/